# Oracle: partition a table with more than 1B records

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle19c, high-volume, subpartition

Database: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0
Issue: in production we have a table with more than 1B records that we are not able to query since the table is not partitioned/indexed. To tune the table we want to partition it, but we have problems due to a high data volume since operation requires a lot CPU and cannot be done in one day.
Steps we want to follow are:

1. create a bkp table
2. truncate original table
3. add partitions, sub-partitions and indexes on original table (partition will be done on date column - daily data, sub-partition will be done on type)
4. reinsert data in table
5. rebuild indexes

Do you have other solution that can be faster, maybe doing this operation on main table without locking it?

Comment: Instead of moving the data twice you may create new table with desired partitioning schema, copy the data into that table and then rename both tables (original -> something, new -> original). You may use `dbms_parallel_execute` package to split tasks by `rowid` and move the data in multiple chuncks reducing `ORA-01555` probability for table readers. Or use `dbms_redefinition` package which will perform maintenance tasks by itself.

Comment: You should be able to partition the table online (i.e. allowing data to be updated in the table whilst the partitioning takes place), e.g. (per 12.2 documentation) https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5. I would create a backup table first, just to be safe. You can also create indexes online.

You'd have to test which approach works best for you, obviously. In your proposed approach, I wouldn't add the indexes until after the data has been inserted.

Comment: It should not be that moving 1 billion records "cannot be done in one day". I can move that much in only a few minutes. Others above have suggested online redefinition which is an option. Another, the fastest but not an online option, is a single CTAS ("create table as select") in which the partitioning scheme is defined in the CTAS itself. To do this you have to list the columns (without the datatypes) so you can then refer to those columns in partitioning DDL clauses. The CTAS move is then followed by a rename to swap the tables. The key thing is however to ensure that you use parallelism.

Comment: @PaulW, Is it possible for you to provide a working sample for your approach. This seems the easiest and fastest possible method.

Comment: The amount of parallelism that can be used will depend upon the physical machine; specifically the number of CPU’s and the IO Bandwidth.